# What is the process of (digital)IC design?

Tags: integrated-circuit, design, microchip

If you're going to design a digital IC from the bottom up, starting with the actual transistors(and passive IC components) that form the logic gates, do you first simulate the logic gates, flip-flops, mux/demuxes as circuits comprised of discrete components to ensure that they work properly before simulating them as an actual integrated circuit? I've tried doing this with CMOS logic gates by constructing them from discrete components using NI MULTISIM 14 but such simulations do not produce working designs. Or is there a different approach to designing an IC and simulating the circuit to see if it works in theory before it is then fabricated and tested....

Comment: Logic simulation is logic simulation. Do it first.

Comment: Sort of - normally you ask your foundry for a "tech library" rather than building your own, though. Most of the design work is done at RTL level in Verilog or VHDL.

Comment: You are not "asking" for a library. You are buyng their specific process, which is based on specific libraries, for a hefty price.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that proper digital IC design is not done **bottom-up** but **top-down** !

You start with a specification of the function which you need. You get this from someone else or write your own.

Then you translate that into Verilog or VHDL and simulate until it does what you think it should do.

Then you generate the netlist from the Verilog or VHDL.

Very likely you will simulate that netlist to verify that it works as expected.

From the netlist a layout is synthesized using the IC manufacturer's libraries. These libraries contain the layouts of all the gates needed (Inverters, AND, OR gates etc) and it contains information on the delay of these gates.

So normally digital designers are not bothered by the actual transistors as the gates are blocks which are ready to use.

The synthesized layout is send to the manufacturer for further processing and mask-making.

The wafers are then processed using these masks.

What I wrote might be wrong in some respects as I am an Analog IC designer, not a digital one. When I need some digital I just draw a schematic with gates directly. This is only suitable for simple functions with only a few gates.
I do sometimes layout my own transistor level gates though.

Comment: Verilog and VHDL are types of RTL code, not a seperate layer. You might model the design matlab style before jumping into RTL though. Synthesis also maps first to generic cells, then to library cells (which are typically composite functions). Sometimes, you might hand-craft a small number of cells to use in a critical region of the design - but that would be a niche role.

Comment: In that case, WHO designs the IC manufacturer libraries? If say, I wanted to create a library of gates how do I make sure that these gate designs actually work?

Comment: OK, I mixed up RTL and netlist, will update. *WHO designs the IC manufacturer libraries?* The foundry which makes the ICs or they hire a company to do that for them. Sometimes this is the company which can also provide simulation tools. As a designer you can just **assume** that the gate designs will work, if they don't then the IC manufacturer screwed up bigtime. It is your task to make the gates work together as a whole.

Comment: Thanks. And in the case of the foundry designers, what process do they use for designing the gates? Do they construct models using discrete components or model the components as part of an integrated circuit? IIRC the design of actual logic gates and op amps from transistors is the domain of <b>microelectronics</b>.

Comment: The gates are made of MOS transistors. Basically a standard recipe is followed to make these transistors. During process development the details of the manufacturing process are determined to make these transistors reliably and wit the required properties. Then test transistors are made. These are measured and the data from that is used to make sets of model parameters, these are then fed to to a transistor model in a simulator allowing designers (like me ;-) ) to design circuits.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, so do you design the actual logic gates yourself given the pre-designed transistors? Or do you design the larger scale IC circuits?

Comment: I sometimes make my own logic cells. From transistors which are  what we call p-cells ( parameterized cells). I can state what length, width, number of fingers I want and then the transistor layout is generated for me. With 2 of those (an NMOS and a PMOS) I can make an inverter. With a couple of hundreds I make more fancy circuits. Combining all those circuits gives us the complete design of a chip. I work on Analog / RF (up to 60 GHz !) circuits and ICs and for those we do not need so many transistors compared to ICs that contain mainly digital circuits (like CPUs, DSPs etc.).

Comment: Foundry logic cells are usually drawn by hand (not using p-cells) to make them smaller. Designing these is a specialist's job. The circuits are simple but you need intricate knowledge of the IC process so that what you draw gives the function you need. And that as dense (small space) as possible. My p-cell based logic cells can be about 50% larger than these hand drawn cells. But if only a few logic gates are needed that is not an issue as most analog cells are much larger anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Digital design is usually broken up into several parts.  One part of that is the design of the transistors, and then library components (logic gates, RAMs, etc.) along with timing models.  The fab figures out how best to make the transistors by running lots of test structures and measuring their characteristics, then constructing device models that capture that behavior.  Then library designers take the transistor designs and build them into component libraries.

Libraries will consist of a plethora of variations of standard gates with different transistor sizes (load capacitance and drive strength) and threshold voltages so they can be 'swapped out' later in the design process to fine tune timing and power consumption.  The library components will also contain simplified models that are derived from transistor level simulations that can be used for static timing analysis and power analysis of a complex digital design.  This all generally gets wrapped up in a 'design kit' from the semiconductor fab.

Digital designers will design their system at a high level, generally with a hardware description language, and perform simulations to make sure the logic is correct.  Then this will be synthesized into gates from the fab's library.  Then floorplanning is done to figure out how to lay out the major chip components.  Then the gates are placed, clock and other high fanout signals are routed, then everything else is routed.  Various analyses are performed to make sure the design will work correctly - timing, power, electromigration, etc.  Sometimes changes have to be made at earlier stages (i.e. RTL) to improve performance.  All of the simulations are performed at different process, voltage, and temperature conditions to make sure that the design will have the best possible yield.  Post-routing simulations are performed that take routing and propagation delays into consideration.  Finally, GDSII design files that define all of the different layers will be generated to send to the fab for manufacture.

Answer (score 0):

You usually start on the RTL level. After that you can synthesize the IC for a specific manufacturing process. The fab will give you their simulation model. You can then simulate on the transistor level.

On the transistor level you mainly need to do: time closure; ensure the clock network is good i.e. monotonic etc.; impedance match the signals; move things around for better performance etc.

I am obviously simplifying it a lot, but you should get the general idea. On the RTL level you ensure it functions as specified. On the transistor level you make sure it works in real life.

Also, verification is a big part of the process. For most ICs you probably have 2 tries to get it right. Formal verification is quite common nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the scale of your digital circuit, but the whole premise of digital design is that the vast majority of circuit design only requires logical validation with a digital simulator (2 or 4 states), rather than analogue validation using spice models and monte-carlo analysis.

To make this abstraction work, you need to make lots of assumptions and design in some margin. This is captured in a small number of parameters for each standard cell (setup, hold, rise time, delay, etc), but even the people who work on chip level layout don't get involved with spice models very often.

The abstractions are safe to make for large designs because there are many typically critical paths, and many eventual components all with individual manufacturing tolerances, so whole circuit performance in a batch tends (by the statistics of large numbers) towards consistent enough behaviour (and the analysis tools are well tuned now compared with 40 years ago).

This is the norm unless you're working at a new cutting edge where you might take a known good logical design as one of the inputs to some analysis of some flow variation, or want to analyse why an abstraction gave an inaccurate result in test silicon.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put my variant of answer. If you're going to design a digital IC… you design it from top-down.

First, your senior technical marketing people define what the IC has to have in order to be marketable and potentially profitable.

Then your senior design manager/architect determines which functional blocks need to be there to accomplish the business goals, and writes device architecture specifications. At the same time upper management, counting future expenses, decides on which  foundry/process to use to accomplish these goals.

Then these functional blocks are either designed to desired specifications, or management decides to buy the IP (Intellectual Property) from some outside design house. Buying external IP might be preferable if the vendor is trusted. Selection and qualification of external IP is a process by itself.

Then integration engineers hook all these IP blocks with internal busses or switch matrices, add wrappers to I/O pad cells, etc, and verification engineers run the entire virtual thing through behavioral simulations to ensure that all configurations/setups and register access are up to architectural specifications. All this work is done virtually in one or another variant of RTL Register Transfer Language, Verilog or VHDL.

The process of designing “the logic gates, flip-flops, mux/demuxes as circuits comprised of discrete components to ensure that they work properly” is normally done by foundry, as a part of so-called “qualification process” for particular “process node”, to ensure that all elements of this “library” function reliably across PVT – Process, Voltage, Temperature ranges, which results in specific gate/block drive data, and annotates timing information. These libraries are part of foundry service, and foundries put enormous effort to produce good working libraries. This is if the design targets ASIC. If the design can be implemented in FPGA,  all this “library hard work” is done by FPGA vendor, but the idea I the same.

Then the layout engineers suggest placement of blocks synthesized from RTL into interconnected library of elements (called mapping), then “placed and routed” using pretty expensive CAD tools. Since now the library elements are not just logical functions, but also have certain propagation timing (aka “back annotated timing”), the entire design runs again through the verification suite of tests, to ensure that all sequential logic meets combinatorial delays for desired clock rate. Closure of timing issues might require some changes in design, and takes time and good care.

When the design meets desired targets, it is “taped out”, meaning that design files are generated and sent to foundry for producing the necessary set of masks and kick off the fabrication process.

Comment: I omitted pin placement and power distribution steps of IC design.